# How to count occurrences with multiple columns in Google Sheet using formulas?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

| Dept | Process | Job No | Job Date | Job Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 123 | 18/7/22 | 12:00 |
| a | w | 123 | 18/7/22 | 13:00 |
| a | y | 123 | 19/7/22 | 10:00 |
| b | z | 456 | 18/7/22 | 14:00 |

and a formula from [ExtendOffice](https://=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A1:A16&%7B%22%22,%22%22%7D,%22select%20Col1,%20count(Col2)%20where%20Col1%20!=%20%27%27%20group%20by%20Col1%20label%20count(Col2)%20%27Count%27%22,1)))

```
=ArrayFormula(QUERY(A1:A&{"",""},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 label count(Col2) 'Count'",1))
```

which gives

| Dept | Count |
| --- | --- |
| a | 3 |
| b | 1 |

As the formula counts the number of occurrences of a value in only one column, how should I modify it to include multiple columns? Say, including Job Date?

| Job Date | Dept | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 18/7/22 | a | 2 |
| 18/7/22 | b | 1 |
| 19/7/22 | a | 1 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below `QUERY()` formula-

```
=QUERY(A1:E5,"select D, A, Count(A) group by D, A label Count(A) 'Count'",1)
```

[image]

Comment: could you explain the syntax or add a link to the documentation about it?

Comment: @L4ZZA See this [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) from google.